# onListItemClick with Multiple Value/Retrieving Value

Tags: android, listview

**I am trying to retrieve the 2nd value from a Arraylist/ArrayAdapter that I have populated.  I am new to Array so please correct me if I am wrong

Q1. I created the Array Favorite. What I think what I created is an Array with two set of value call Detail | Value. example Detail="Yasmin",Value="8". Is this correct?

Q2.  I have assign the Favorite Array to the mFavlist listview.  During the OnItemClick I can return the label "Yasmin" by the position of the listview.  What I would like to do is return the value of "8".  What would be the best way to do this?

Please let me know if I am on the right track via the array and  adapter**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class lister extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        TextView txHomeTeam;
        protected ListView mFavlist;
        protected ArrayList<Favorite> fakeFavs = new ArrayList<Favorite>();

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
       this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

        this.txHomeTeam = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.title);

        fakeFavs.add(new Favorite("John", "1"));
        fakeFavs.add(new Favorite("Yasmin", "8"));
        fakeFavs.add(new Favorite("Jack", "10"));

        //this.mFavlist = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list_favorites);
        this.mFavlist = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list_favorites);
        initListView();

        mFavlist.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        mFavlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View view,
                                           int position, long id) {

                                // user clicked a list item, 
    //and read the value from <Favorite>.value
                                //txHomeTeam.setText=????

                                }
        });
    }

   public void refreshFavListItems() {
            mFavlist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Favorite>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fakeFavs));
    }

    public void initListView() {
        /* Loads the items to the ListView. */
        refreshFavListItems();

    }
protected class Favorite {
        protected String Detail;
        protected String value;

        protected Favorite(String Detail, String value) {
                this.Detail = Detail;
                this.value = value;

        }
        public String toString() {
                return Detail;
        }
}
}
```

Comment: You have not asked any questions here. What is the problem? What are the symptoms? Are you getting error messages?

Comment: my apologies if there is any confusion, I am having problem with the code block. I will update the main part

Answer (score 0):

Use the `position` parameter to get to the correct position in your adapter

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View view,
                                           int position, long id) {
    Favorite selectedFav=lister.this.fakeFavs.getItem(position)
}
```